# Latex tabu-package

Tags: latex

Many years I've successfully used the tabu-package to create tables like shown in the code-example below. I produced an extended number of those tables in an documentation and so want to avoid major changes.
Since the June update of MiKTeX to Version 21.6 all the tables show the same error-message like:

Row  xx  Dimension too large. \end{longtabu}

As soon as I use one of the previous MiKTeX Version e.g. 21.3. proper tables  are produced.
Are there any ideas what the reason could be and how to circumnavigate the problem?

My code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{longtable}              
\usepackage{tabu}   
\begin{document}

  \begin{spacing}{2}
      \begin{longtabu}to\textwidth{lXl}             
         200 A  & & 300 B \\
         100 C & & 200 D \\
         30 E  & & 600 F \\
         80 G & & 50 H \\
         0,5 I & &3000 J \\
      \end{longtabu}
  \end{spacing}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Although this question is on topic for SO , there is a specific [TeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com) where it is more likely to attract an answer.

Comment: The `tabu` package is more or less totally broken and only held together by some pieces of duck tape. Don't use it.

Comment: please read https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu

Comment: I welcome the information given in both answers and would like to thank both participants.